# Need a function for Url Slug

Tags: php

Right now iam learning how to make a MVC Framework and iam stuck at the Routing. I have no idee how to make the slug.

At the beginning the Array looks like this

```php
[
    "_name" => "admin",
    "_path" => "/admin/edit/{id}",
    "_controller" => "AdminController@editAction",
    "_method" => "GET"

]
```

And when the Url is called like this: http://localhost/admin/edit/1

the Array sould look like this

```php
[
    "_name" => "admin",
    "_path" => "/admin/edit/{id}",
    "_controller" => "AdminController@editAction",
    "_method" => "GET",
    "_params" => [
           "id" => 1
     ]

]
```

Right now iam checking if a part of the _path equals the requested Url and then get the Slug and send it to the RouteCollection Class

```php
public static function match($uri)  {
        $hasPath = false;
        $route = RouteCollection::getRoute();
        foreach($route as $i):
            if(strpos($i['_path'], $uri) !== false):
                preg_replace_callback("#\{(\w++)(<.*?>)?(\?[^\}]*+)?\}#", function($mm) {                           
                    RouteCollection::setParams($mm[1], ???); // $mm[1] = placeholder without {}
                }, $i['_path']);
            endif;
        endforeach;
    }
```

But how can i say that everything behind (admin/edit) beloags to the right slug

Comment: Well, you can't, and usually there are some rules that help to resolve that, e.g.: 1) slug cannot contain `/` and 2) first matching rule wins. So, if you have a match, that's it, you found correct route.

Comment: @blackfire which framework you use?

Comment: I make my one Framework to learn because its more fun for me this way :)

Comment: You're going about it the wrong way..
Instead of doing a regex on the slug, replace the parameters in it with the given one, and then do a full check ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think i found a solution for my problem with this Code i can save the slug and the value for it in a array in the route

```php
public static function generate($uri) {

        $routes = RouteCollection::getRoute();
        self::$uri = $uri;
        self::$breakedParam = explode("-", $uri);    

        self::$name = explode("/", self::$breakedParam[0]);

        if($uri == "/"):
            self::$name = "app";
        else:
            self::$name = self::$name[1];
        endif;

        if(\array_key_exists(self::$name, $routes)):
            $routeUri = explode("-", $routes[self::$name]['_path']);
            // Check for slug   
            \preg_replace_callback("#\{(\w++)(<.*?>)?(\?[^\}]*+)?\}#", function($m){
                    //Check if breakedParam has the Key and add value to Array
                    if(\array_key_exists(self::$integer, self::$breakedParam)):
                        self::$params[$m[1]] = self::$breakedParam[self::$integer];

                        self::$integer++;
                        RouteCollection::setParams(self::$name, self::$params);
                    endif;
            }, $routes[self::$name]["_path"]);
        else:
            echo "existirt nicht";
        endif;
    }
```

Its not the perfect way i belive but it works for now

If u have a better way iam open for idees